# Max array size using #define

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault, c-preprocessor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [stack overflow c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182127/stack-overflow-c)

I have the following program for generating prime numbers:

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<cmath>
#include<algorithm>

#define MAX 10000000
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    bool prime[MAX+1];
    fill_n(prime,MAX+1,true);
    int baseSqrt,i,j;
    baseSqrt = int(sqrt(MAX+1));
    for(i=2;i<=baseSqrt;i++){
        if(prime[i]){
            for(j=i+i;j<=MAX;j+=i){
                    prime[j]=false;
            }   
        }   
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

The program works fine for MAX value = 1000000. But when I increase the value to 10000000 the program gives segfault. I tried using gdb but it stops on main giving segfault there. I am using a 64 bit OS. Even if I remove MAX and write 10000000 rather than MAX, I get the same error. Where am I going wrong? Please help.

Comment: The stack's size is usually very limited compared to the total amount of memory you can use.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't declare very large arrays as local variables (i.e. on the stack), as the stack size is usually quite limited.  Instead, dynamically allocate them with `new[]` and `delete[]`.  Or for idiomatic C++, use a container class like `std::deque`.

Comment: Whats the max size that i can use? Is it around 1MB? because with #define MAX 7000000 program works fine

Comment: Why `new[]` and `delete[]`? Why not `std::vector`?

Comment: @Nawaz: Why `std::vector`? Why not `std::deque`?

Comment: @Tim: That would also work. The point however is: avoid `new` and `delete`.

Comment: @Nawaz: Argh, except in this case, the type in question is `bool`, and [`std::vector<bool>` is a mess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670308/alternative-to-vectorbool)!

Comment: doesnt vector slow down the program? I dont know. Just asking. what is faster between the two - dynamic array (new, delete) or vector <bool> ?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: You can use `std::vector<char>` instead of the messy `std::vector<bool>`.

Comment: @ShehbazJaffer: It shouldn't really slow anything down.

Comment: @ShehbazJaffer, You can't absolutely know for sure in each case until you measure, and you shouldn't measure until you have to. Worry about working code before premature optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, would it not be a reasonable idea to make "prime" a global variable. I do understand that global variables aren't always a good solution, but for this particular case, it would be a fairly obvious solution. It's not like MAX isn't a constant, so using new/delete or vector as a solution seems a little unnecessary.

And to answer the question of "is if slower to use 'new' vs global variable', then I can say that it's probably irrelevant. I used `#define MAX 1000000000` in the above code, moved prime to be a global, and ran it using time, then altered the code to use new/delete, and it took around 0.5s longer - but the overall runtime is 20.4 or 20.9 seconds, so it's about 2% of the total runtime, and I'm pretty sure more than 2% can be gained by doing other things.